# Multiple JSON Objects into Canvas

Tags: javascript, json, canvas, draw

I am basically creating a canvas application where a user can see the drawing of something else, a lot like DrawSomething.

I can get one string to work ex:

```
var points = JSON.parse ('[{"x":10,"y":20,"strokeStyle":"FF0000"},{"x":20,"y":30,"strokeStyle":"FF0000"}]');
```

but not when i have multiples:

```
var points = JSON.parse ('[{"x":10,"y":20,"strokeStyle":"FF0000"},
{"x":20,"y":30,"strokeStyle":"FF0000"}],[{"x":30,"y":40,"strokeStyle":"00FF00"},
{"x":10,"y":20,"strokeStyle":"FF0000"}],[{"x":50,"y":100,"strokeStyle":"0000FF"},
{"x":70,"y":120,"strokeStyle":"0000FF"}]');
```

any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your JSON is invalid. It contains an array of arrays. You need to surround the outer array with square brackets, like this:

var points = JSON.parse ('**[**[{"x":10,"y":20,"strokeStyle":"FF0000"},{"x":20,"y":30,"strokeStyle":"FF0000"}],[{"x":30,"y":40,"strokeStyle":"00FF00"},{"x":10,"y":20,"strokeStyle":"FF0000"}],[{"x":50,"y":100,"strokeStyle":"0000FF"},{"x":70,"y":120,"strokeStyle":"0000FF"}]**]**');